# Different results in grep results when using --color=always option

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I ran into this problem with grep and would like to know if it's a bug or not. The reproducible scenario is a file with the contents:

```
string
string-
```

and save it as 'file'. The goal is to use grep with --color=always to output 'string' while excluding 'string-'. Without --color, the following works as expected:

```
$ grep string file | grep -v string-
```

but using --color outputs both instances:

```
$ grep --color=always string file | grep -v string-
```

I experimented with several variations but it seems `--color` breaks the expected behavior. Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding something? My assumption is that passing `--color` should have no effect on the outcome.

Comment: Try `grep --color=always string file > f`. Now open `f` in an editor that can view control characters - there should be some [color escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_sequences) inserted at various, possibly unexpected, locations.

Comment: or possibly expected locations, such as right before and after 'string' :)

Comment: The question is whether or not grep should handle this case gracefully. Specifically, whether or not --color is intended to have the identical behavior as without it, aside from highlighting matched text.

Comment: No, it shouldn't - because it doesn't. To do so implicitly would be add additional guesswork interpretation. Since --color=auto will correctly not emit the escapes when piped so it's really operator error to force color output in this case.

Comment: you can reverse these operations: `grep -v string- file | grep --color=always string`

Comment: Indeed, `grep --color=always -v string- file | grep string` seems to work just the same. This seems to be a bug to me but I digress. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Jake Gould's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24093396/45375) provides a great analysis of what actually happens, but let me try to phrase it differently:

`--color=always` uses [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) for coloring.

In other words: **`--color=always` by design ALTERS its output**, because it must add the requisite escape sequences to achieve coloring.

**Never use `--color=always`, unless you know the output is *expected* to contain ANSI escape sequences** - typically, for human eyeballs on a terminal.

**If you're not sure how the input is processed, use `--color=auto`**, which - I believe - causes `grep` to apply coloring *only if* its stdout is connected to a *terminal*.

I a given pipeline, it **typically only makes sense to apply `--color=auto` (or `--color=always`) to a `grep` command that is the LAST command** in the pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `--color` grep adds ANSI (I believe?) color coding. So your text which looks like this:

```
string
string-
```

Will actually look like this in terms of pure, unprocessed ASCII text:

```
^[[01;31m^[[Kstring^[[m^[[K
^[[01;31m^[[Kstring^[[m^[[K-
```

There is some nice info provided in [this question thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739252/grep-through-colored-text-e-g-gcc-colorgcc-grep-regexp) including this great [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14740398/117259).

> My assumption is that passing `--color` should have no effect on the outcome.

Nope. The purpose of `grep`—as most all Unix/Linux tools—is to provide a basic simple service & do that well. And that service is to search a plain-text (key here) input file based on a patter & return the output. The `--color` option is a small nod to the fact that we are humans & staring at screens with uncolored text all day can drive you nuts. Color coding makes work easier.

So color coding with ANSI is usually considered a final step in a process. It’s not the job of `grep` to assume that if it comes across ANSI in it’s input it should ignore it. Perhaps a case could be made to add a `--decolor` option to `grep`, but I doubt that is a feature worth the effort.

`grep` is a base level plain-text parsing tool. Nothing more & nothing less.

Comment: So there is no reason to file a bug report then. Thanks.